# All Sharepoint 2010 Lists not showing title on edit or add

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have Sharepoint 2010.
Everything was fine, until suddenly Lists are not showing title on editing or adding.. I even tried creating new lists, same problem.
Any idea why this happened & what can I do?

Comment: This question is probably better asked on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: found the solution: just go: Site Settings  --> Site Content Types -->  Item  -- >Change Content Type

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to main Site then,
2. Go to Site Actions then,
3. Go to  Site Settings then,
4. Go to (Galleries) Site Content Types
5. In List Content Type, click on Item
6. Click on the "Title" under columns and then make sure you choose required.